# jQuery avoid toggle div from hiding when on a certain area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some jquery that does a link menu hover effect.

My problem is that when I move the mouse to go towards the hovered (#test) div, the div hides so I never get to be able to click on the links below.

Here's the code:

```
//HTML

<li id="hoverer" class="tab-link" data-tab="ideas_by_stage" style="position:relative">Hover here...</li>

<div id="test" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:999999;border:1px solid grey;width:200px;padding:4px 10px;left:170px;background-color:white;">

    <div class="btn"><a href="">Option 1</a></div>
    <div class="btn">Option 2</div>
    <div class="btn">Option 3</div>
    <div class="btn">Option 4</div>

</div>

//jQuery

$( "#hoverer" ).hover(function() {

      $('#test').toggle();

});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code work fine, if you move in red border can click on links , see this :**

```js
 $( "#hoverer" ).hover(function() {

      $('#test').toggle();
   })
```

```css
li {
      border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<li id="hoverer" class="tab-link" data-tab="ideas_by_stage" style="position:relative">Hover here...

<div id="test" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:999999;border:1px solid grey;width:200px;padding:4px 10px;left:170px;background-color:white;">

    <div class="btn"><a href="">Option 1</a></div>
    <div class="btn">Option 2</div>
    <div class="btn">Option 3</div>
    <div class="btn">Option 4</div>

</div>
    </li>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**but best way is use click event ,See below Example :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#hoverer").on("click",function(){
        $("#test").toggle(500);
    })
    
})
```

```html
<li id="hoverer" class="tab-link" data-tab="ideas_by_stage" style="position:relative">Click For Show / Hidden
        </li>

        <div id="test" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:999999;border:1px solid grey;width:200px;padding:4px 10px;left:170px;background-color:white;">

    <div class="btn"><a href="">Option 1</a></div>
    <div class="btn">Option 2</div>
    <div class="btn">Option 3</div>
    <div class="btn">Option 4</div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```js
$( "#hoverer" ).hover(function() {
      $('#test').fadeIn();
});

$( "#test" ).hover(function() {
      $(this).fadeIn();
}, function() {
      $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <li id="hoverer" class="tab-link" data-tab="ideas_by_stage" style="position:relative">Hover here...</li>

 <div id="test" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:999999;border:1px solid grey;width:200px;padding:4px 10px;left:170px;background-color:white;">

     <div class="btn"><a href="">Option 1</a></div>
     <div class="btn">Option 2</div>
     <div class="btn">Option 3</div>
     <div class="btn">Option 4</div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a different approach:

- hoverer: on mouseenter show test
- test: on mouseleave hide test

Adjust the dimensions of hoverer and test element so that this approach can work (i.e.: if you leave the div but enter in the li area you get two consecutive events: hide + show).

The snippet:

```js
$( "#hoverer" ).on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  $('#test').show();
});
$('#test').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $('#test').hide();
});
```

```css
#hoverer {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li id="hoverer" class="tab-link" data-tab="ideas_by_stage" style="position:relative">Hover here...</li>

<div id="test" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:999999;border:1px solid grey;width:200px;padding:4px 10px;left:170px;background-color:white;">

    <div class="btn"><a href="">Option 1</a></div>
    <div class="btn">Option 2</div>
    <div class="btn">Option 3</div>
    <div class="btn">Option 4</div>

</div>
```